# расширение boot ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

Я обычно пользуюсь gparted но тут такая проблема, мне не удается расширить раздел boot
вот скрин [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле оказалось, что расширить бут с моей схемой-разметки не возможно. насколько я понял проблему, т.к они лежат типа в разных логических томах* поэтому в одном томе есть место, а в томе где сформирован boot  - места нет.  Поэтому пришлось переустовить и разметить более правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе надо переместить расширенный раздел вправо и всё, что внутри него. Перед перемещением лучше сделать бэкап и использовать `Gparted Live`, чтобы точно ничего не мешало. Если переместить не получится, то тогда раздвинь расширенный раздел до конца, перемести внутренние разделы вправо, а потом подвинь расширенный.

Comment: я не знаю как переместить раздел, можете дать ссылку где почитать?

Comment: Мышкой перетащить не пробовал? Посмотри контекстное меню.

Comment: пробовал -элементы зафиксированы

Comment: Ты делал это с livecd?

Comment: да, с загрузочной флешки

Comment: А extended partition расширяется?

Comment: нет не расширяется

Comment: Значит ты как-то не так делаешь. Разделы все размонтированы?